# swinging of RTSP streams bandwidth?

Tags: camera, wireshark, rtsp, rtp

I have multiple cameras of different types and I had an issue, which my stream lost frames during streaming, so I limited the bandwidth in cameras setting. but I wonder why some of cameras bandwidth are swinging but a few others are nearly stable. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poj50.png) is my configuration in `wireshark` app.

I'm not sure if its true, but I just limited bandwidth of all cameras in 2000 bit/s or maximum 2500 bit/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your camera utilizes the H.264 or H.265 codecs, which are widely regarded as today's industry standards. In scenarios where there are no significant changes within the scene, such as lack of movement, the bandwidth requirements remain relatively stable. However, when there is noticeable activity or movement within the frame, the bandwidth consumption fluctuates.

You can read more about that [here](https://ottverse.com/i-p-b-frames-idr-keyframes-differences-usecases/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm new in this field. How can I check if my bandwidth is enough sometimes say every 20 minutes, two same cameras suddenly disconnect for a few seconds and then they reconnect. what would be the problem?

Comment: You should set a constant bitrate in the camera that fits to your Network.

Comment: may I ask, what are the advantages and disadvantages of variable bitrate over constant bit rate?

Comment: Setting a H.264 stream to Constant Bitrate (CBR) ensures predictable bandwidth usage and simpler network planning but can waste bandwidth and storage during simple scenes. Variable Bitrate (VBR) adjusts to the scene's complexity, offering better video quality for complex scenes but with unpredictable bandwidth use, making network planning more challenging.